# Can I use devise encrypted_password with custom authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a rails 4 app with devise authentication. I am rebuilding from scratch and would like to write my own authentication system but I have users stored in the database, whose password is stored as `encrypted_password`, which is what devise uses to store the hashed password. I understand that using `bcrypt` I should have a `password_digest`column.

My question is twofold: will bcrypt be able to read what I have stored in my devise `encrypted_password` column and if so, can I simply rename that database column to `password_digest`or will this cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read, yes, you should be able to just rename the column and use it with your custom authentication.

Refs:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L149-L151

> ```
> module Devise
>   def self.bcrypt(klass, password)
>     ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "Devise.bcrypt is deprecated; use Devise::Encryptor.digest instead"
>     Devise::Encryptor.digest(klass, password)
>   end
>
>   module Models
>     module DatabaseAuthenticatable
>
>       # Digests the password using bcrypt. Custom encryption should override
>       # this method to apply their own algorithm.
>       #
>       # See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise-encryptable for examples
>       # of other encryption engines.
>       def password_digest(password)
>         Devise::Encryptor.digest(self.class, password)
>       end
> ```

and:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/encryptor.rb#L5-L10

> ```
> module Devise
>   module Encryptor
>     def self.digest(klass, password)
>       if klass.pepper.present?
>         password = "#{password}#{klass.pepper}"
>       end
>       ::BCrypt::Password.create(password, cost: klass.stretches).to_s
>     end
> ```